# Why can I change this const NSMutableSring?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, constants

I have this sample code:

```
const NSMutableString *const foobar = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello"];
[foobar appendString:@" World"];
NSLog(@"String: %@", foobar);
```

and it outputs:

> String: Hello World

Shouldn't my variable be `const` (as well as the pointer)? Therefore I should not be able to modify it.

C++ behaves the way I expect

```
int main() {
    const std::string *const s = new std::string("hello");
    s->append(" world");
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
$ g++ test.c++
test.c++: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c++:7:20: error: passing ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::append(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  s->append(" world");
```

I know I shouldn't use `const` with mutable, but that doesn't change the fact, that the mutable should be `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct, the type *pointer to a constant T* is silently changed to *pointer to a T* in the cases where *T* is an Objective-C class.

This isn't technically a deviation from the semantics of `const` in C(++) as there are no Objective-C class types in C(++) and they are therefore not covered by the C(++) Standards.

Objective-C itself is not defined by any formal description, well enough a Standard. *The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language*, 2009, makes no mention of constant semantics, and is also long since abandoned as a reference and has not been replaced.

In other words I cannot direct you to any definitive document that states that `const` is silently elided for Objective-C class types, but that is how the compilers behave.

If you want "constant" objects you have to follow the Objective-C mutable/immutable class pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it works like this: "const NSMutableString * const foobar" causes two things to be made constant: the ptr to the object, and the object itself. However, I bet the object itself is simply a struct of pointers, and those pointers aren't constant.

In c++, the way you make something immutable is to declare it const, in Objective-C you choose the regular version, which is usually immutable by default.

Answer (score -1):

`const` means that the address of the pointer is constant and so you can change/append the string. Also the best practice is, always use const with `NSString` . Hope this helps.

Comment: The other const on the declaration line means that the contents of the pointer are const as well. "const int * const x" is a constant ptr to an int const. But I am wondering about the Mutable property.

Comment: Exactly const is not meant to be used with mutable.

Comment: I know that it is not supposed to be used like this, but it should be const anyway.

Comment: I bet we could find a bunch of people who would disagree. After all, by choosing the Mutable version, you are declaring your desire to be able to change the contents.

Comment: NSMutableString – Should be used when you are physically changing the value of an existing string, without completely discarding the old value (i.e. adding a character to the beginning or end, modifying a character in the middle etc).


NSString – Can never be changed after it has been created, only overwritten with a completly new string.  Most NSStrings (including @”Constant Strings”) are autoreleased.  NStrings occupy a fixed number of bytes in memory and are the most efficient.

Comment: This interesting thing here is that the const keyword doesn't seem to actually effect the contents. I suspect that has to do with the fact that it's an objective-c object, which are decidedly different from c++ objects, despite doing the same job.

Comment: The use of `const` has defined semantics in `C++`. You're expecting that those semantics cross over to `Objective C`. That is simply not the case as, unless you're compiling objective C++, I don't think `const` enforcement actually happens.

Comment: Additionally, you can't const-decorate Objective C methods, which would be essential for a functional `const` environment

Comment: @ShoaibRaza - The question defines a "constant pointer to a constant", there are two constants in the type given, only one applies to the pointer.

Comment: @CRD one constant applies to a memory which shall remain constant but the other constant in the above question is for the mutable part which acutally is not meant to be kept constant as the word 'mutable' says it all that I am MUTABLE and its literal meaning is 'liable to change' . That is why my friend I am saying again and again that constant should be used for NSString not NSMutableString .